# Sinus equality proof

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

> Show that the following equalities hold true for every $n$ from $\mathbb{N}$ and
>   every $x$ from $\mathbb{R}$
>
> $$\sin^{(n)}(x)=\sin(x+n\fracπ2)$$

How do I solve this?

Comment: It's not true as stated.

Comment: This not correct.  It must be sth like $sin^{(n)}(x)=sin(x+n\fracπ2)$.If it is as I said, use induction.

Comment: @hhsaffar yup,that's the way it is.How is induction used for derivatives like this?

Comment: @MrMime I left a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Show $sin^{(1)}(x)=sin(x+\frac\pi2)$

Then suppose for $n$ we have $sin^{(n)}(x)=sin(x+n\fracπ2)$, show that $sin^{(n+1)}(x)=sin(x+(n+1)\fracπ2)$. Do this by differentiating $sin^{(n)}(x)$ once.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sin\left(x+\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right)&=\sin x\cos\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right)+\cos x\sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right) \\
&=\sin x\cos(n\pi+\pi/2)+\cos x\sin(n\pi+\pi/2) \\
&=-\sin x\sin(n\pi)+\cos x \cos(n\pi) \\
\end{align}$$

You can clearly see that this is not $\sin^n(x)$.

Comment: Technically, this is not the way to show that it is not $\sin^n(x)$, actually one should find some $x_0$ such that $\sin^n(x_0) \neq \sin(x_0+\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2})$.

Comment: Yeah, but I started out trying to prove it and realized it was wrong, so here you go.